# How to click Button adjacent to a specific text in Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am stuck at this problem wherein i require to click on a specific button adjacent to some text in my app.

For eg: Let this be the one of the screens of my app with the following text.

```
    xxxx-xxxx-xxxx  Button1 Button2
    yyyy-yyyy-yyyy  Button3 Button4
```

Now i want to click on Button1 if the text i am passing as input matches "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx". And, Button3 if the input text matches "yyyy-yyyy-yyyy".

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fgr4uz4mm2mfm6/Untitled.png refer to this link to see how it looks like.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is this xxx-xxx is this textview or edittext?

Comment: Can you give any more information about how these views are structuredm e.g. are they within the same parentview. Your layout xml would be helpful.

Comment: user3395743 : i am not sure of what it is, either a text view or an edit text or it may also be a label. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made an assumption that they are in the same Viewgroup. If this is the case then it is not so bad.

What you need to do is break this down in to a set of problems

1) Find the view, this is pretty easy solo.getText(String text) will return the text view that has that text or getEditText(String text) will work if it is an edit text.

2) find the parent view in common between the view you found and the button to click. you can do this by calling getParent() on the view returned above and casting it to a (ViewGroup)

3) find the text view you want from that view parent, the simplest if they all have the same structure is to use getChildAt(i) on the view group above, where i will probably be 2 from the strucutre you mention. You will need to cast this to a button.

putting this all together it will look soemthing like:

```
View view = solo.getEditText("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"); //or solo.getText("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx")
ViewGroup viewGroupContaingTextAndButton = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
Button button = viewGroupContaingTextAndButton.getChildAt(2);
```

You should be able to refactor that into a nice easy re-usable method.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fgr4uz4mm2mfm6/Untitled.png please refer the link to see how it looks like.

Comment: Sadly i cannot access dropbox urls where I am. If you cannot host it elsewhere It will have to wait until later!

Comment: can you kindly suggest some other way to send the image to you?

Comment: A picture does not help, you will need to use the hierarchy viewer or get the source of the layouts xml. I suspect the code i pasted will work though, have you tried it? (my guess would be the getText() version.

Comment: i achieved the desired output. Thanks!